# Python/Django: Create table with two primary_key using cql engine

Tags: django, django-models, cassandra, primary-key, cql3

I want create a table with two primary_key by it's django model as below:

```
class UserView(Model):
    email= columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    entryLink= columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    date= columns.Date(default=datetime.date.today())
```

but when I want create table as below:

```
>>> from cqlengine import connection
>>> from cqlengine.management import create_table
>>> from MainAPP.models import UserView
>>> connection.setup(['127.0.0.1:9160'])
>>> create_table(UserView)
```

I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "H:\Web-Programming\Python\Project\Prexter\Virtual-Environment\Lib\site-packages\cqlengine\management.py", line 97, in create_table
execute(qs)
  File "H:\Web-Programming\Python\Project\Prexter\Virtual-Environment\Lib\site-packages\cqlengine\connection.py", line 172, in execute
return connection_pool.execute(query, params)
  File "H:\Web-Programming\Python\Project\Prexter\Virtual-Environment\Lib\site-packages\cqlengine\connection.py", line 164, in execute
    raise CQLEngineException(unicode(ex))
CQLEngineException: Bad Request: Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column entryLink
```

When I remove **primary_key** property from **entryLink** field, I have no error! but I want define entryLink as a primary_key! What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database table cannot have 2 primary key. If you are looking for a Composite Primary Key, [Django does not support that yet](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys#Multi-ColumnPrimaryKeysupport).

Now, what you *might* be looking for is `unique=True` (a candidate key).

```
class UserView(Model):
    email= columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    entryLink= columns.Text(unique=True)
    date= columns.Date(default=datetime.date.today())
```

You can also read [this post for a better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table)

Comment: This is true! But note that my database is cassandra! in this code my first primary_key will set as a partition_key and other primary_keys must be my clustering keys! please read this section: [https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html#column-options](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html#column-options)

Comment: I still dont buy the fact that a table should have multiple `primary` keys. Candidate keys - YES, but `primary` key ?? Even if cassandra supports it, django does not.

Comment: I do see `In CQL, there are 2 types of primary keys: partition keys and clustering keys. As with CQL, the first primary key is the partition key, and all others are clustering keys, unless partition keys are specified manually using partition_key` - Now, django would not support this by default. However, you can take a look at 3rd party apps like `django-nonrel` and see how it is implemented there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.as a result I have a serious truble with django! because cassandra isn't a relational database like MySQL, SqlServer, oracle,...! It's a no sql database which have a different structure completely! in cassandra we can define many primary_keys. you can se this example : [Cassandra Example](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/)

Comment: I got that. I have worked with non-relational databases, but never cassandra. I have not faced this issue. Sorry for not being of much help. I was talking about [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) which might offer some support (Have not worked on it myself though).

Answer (score 1):

I found My Answer! This is a funny bug!
I have a **capitalized character** among **entryLink** field, and it caused considered error! This is so funny! because this applies to primary_key only! and it isn't true about other fields!!! **primary_keys can't have a capitalized character among!**

**My modified code:**

```
class UserView(Model):
    email= columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    link= columns.Text(primary_key = True)
    date= columns.Date(default=datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: I think what you need is partition_key instead of multiple parimary_keys
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.html#cassandra.cqlengine.columns.Column.partition_key