# Foreign key as a composite key - Spring data JPA mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mapping, spring-data-jpa

[image: Table Mapping]

I am trying to create the above mapping using spring data jpa but stuck in the part where (**cus_id , c_date**) is used as a composite key in Table c , which is also a composite key in Table B .  **cus_id** in Table B is a foreign key to tableA.

How to map this using jpa ?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385658/jpa-how-to-make-composite-foreign-key-part-of-composite-primary-key

Comment: Do you want Table B as entity as well or a ManyToMany between Table A and Table C?

Comment: Table B has one to many relation with table C.