# Problem whet embedded objects: Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables in a MySQL Database. One is named documento_tributario_electronico and the other is named detalle.

The documento_Tributario_electronico table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `documento_tributario_electronico` (
    `tipo_documento` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `numero` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `fecha_emision` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'curdate()',
    `indicador_no_rebaja` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipo_despacho` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `indicador_traslado` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipo_impresion` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `indicador_servicio` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `indicador_montos_brutos` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipo_transaccion_compra` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipo_transaccion_venta` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `forma_pago` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
    `fecha_cancelacion` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_cancelado` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `saldo_insoluto` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `periodo_desde` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `periodo_hasta` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `medio_pago` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `tipo_cuenta_pago` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `cuenta_pago` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `banco_pago` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `terminos_pago_codigo` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `terminos_pago_glosa` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `terminos_pago_dias` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_vencimiento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tipo_factura_especial` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rut_empresa` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `rut_mandante` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `rut_cliente` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `rut_solicitante` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `patente` VARCHAR(8) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `rut_transportista` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `rut_chofer` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `nombre_chofer` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `direccion_destino` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `comuna_destino` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ciudad_destino` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_neto` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_exento` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_base_faenamiento_carne` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_base_margen_comercializacion` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tasa_iva` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '9.99',
    `iva` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `iva_propio` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `iva_terceros` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `iva_no_retenido` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aplica_credito_especial_empresas_constructoras` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `monto_total` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `tipo_otra_moneda` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `factor_conversion_otra_moneda` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tipo_documento`, `numero`, `rut_empresa`) USING BTREE
)
```

The detalle table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle` (
    `rut_empresa` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `tipo_documento` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `numero` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `numero_detalle` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `agenteRetenedor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `monto_base_faenamiento_carne` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_base_margen_comercializacion` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `precio_unitario_neto_consumidor_final` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigo_producto` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `descripcion_adicional` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `cantidad_referencia` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cantidad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `fecha_elaboracion` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_vencimiento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `descuento_pct` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `descuento_monto` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `recargo_pct` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `recargo_monto` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigo_impuesto_retencion1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigo_impuesto_retencion2` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monto_item` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`rut_empresa`, `tipo_documento`, `numero`, `numero_detalle`) USING BTREE
)
```

Also, I'm developing a Spring Boot Application with Spring JPA and Lombok. Due to the fact that both tables have composite primary keys, I had to create a Embeddable class for each entity's Id. Also, there is a relationship one to many from documento_tributario_electronico to detalle.

I implemented the entities for both tables as follows:

The DocumentoTributarioElectronico entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name="documento_tributario_electronico")
public class DocumentoTributarioElectronico implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private DocumentoTributarioElectronicoPK id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("rutEmpresa")
    private Empresa emisor;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tipoDocumento")
    private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_emision", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaEmision;
    
    @Column(name="indicador_no_rebaja", nullable=true)
    private Integer indicadorNoRebaja;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_despacho", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private TipoDespacho tipoDespacho;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="indicador_traslado", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private IndicadorTraslado indicadorTraslado;
    
    @Column(name="tipo_impresion", length=1, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N'")
    private String tipoImpresion;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="indicador_servicio", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private IndicadorServicio indicadorServicio;
    
    @Column(name="indicador_montos_brutos", nullable=true)
    private Integer indicadorMontosBrutos;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_transaccion_compra", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private TipoTransaccionCompra tipoTransaccionCompra;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_transaccion_venta", referencedColumnName="codigo", columnDefinition="INT(11) DEFAULT 1")
    private TipoTransaccionVenta tipoTransaccionVenta;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="forma_pago", referencedColumnName="codigo", columnDefinition="INT(11) DEFAULT 2")
    private FormaPago formaPago;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_cancelacion", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaCancelacion;
    
    @Column(name="monto_cancelado", nullable=true)
    private Long montoCancelado;
    
    @Column(name="saldo_insoluto", nullable=true)
    private Long saldoInsoluto;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="documentoTributarioElectronico")
    private List<MontoPago> montosPago;
    
    @Column(name="periodo_desde", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date periodoDesde;
    
    @Column(name="periodo_hasta", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date periodoHasta;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="medio_pago", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private MedioPago medioPago;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_cuenta_pago", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private TipoCuentaPago tipoCuentaPago;
    
    @Column(name="cuenta_pago", length=20, nullable=true)
    private String cuentaPago;
    
    @Column(name="banco_pago", length=40, nullable=true)
    private String bancoPago;
    
    @Column(name="terminos_pago_codigo", length=4, nullable=true)
    private String terminosPagoCodigo;
    
    @Column(name="terminos_pago_glosa", length=100, nullable=true)
    private String terminosPagoGlosa;
    
    @Column(name="terminos_pago_dias", nullable=true)
    private Integer terminosPagoDias;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_vencimiento", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaVencimiento;
    
    @Column(name="rut_mandante", length=10, nullable=true)
    private String rutMandante;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="rut_cliente", referencedColumnName="rut", nullable=false)
    private Cliente cliente;
    
    @Column(name="rut_solicitante", length=10, nullable=true)
    private String rutSolicitante;
    
    @Column(name="patente", length=8, nullable=true)
    private String patente;
    
    @Column(name="rut_transportista", length=10, nullable=true)
    private String rutTransportista;
    
    @Column(name="rut_chofer", length=10, nullable=true)
    private String rutChofer;
    
    @Column(name="nombre_chofer", length=30, nullable=true)
    private String nombreChofer;
    
    @Column(name="direccion_destino", length=70, nullable=true)
    private String direccionPostal;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ciudad_destino", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private Ciudad ciudadPostal;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="comuna_destino", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private Comuna comunaPostal;
    
    @Column(name="monto_neto", nullable=true)
    private Long montoNeto;
    
    @Column(name="monto_exento", nullable=true)
    private Long montoExento;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_faenamiento_carne", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseFaenamientoCarne;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_margen_comercializacion", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseMargenComercializacion;
    
    @Column(name="tasa_iva", nullable=true)
    private Float tasaIva;
    
    @Column(name="iva", nullable=true)
    private Long iva;
    
    @Column(name="iva_propio", nullable=true)
    private Long ivaPropio;
    
    @Column(name="iva_terceros", nullable=true)
    private Long ivaTerceros;
    
    @Column(name="iva_no_retenido", nullable=true)
    private Long ivaNoRetenido;
    
    @Column(name="aplica_credito_especial_empresas_constructoras", columnDefinition="TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0")
    private Boolean aplicaCreditoEspecialEmpresasConstructoras;
    
    @Column(name="monto_total", nullable=false)
    private Long montoTotal;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_otra_moneda", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    private Moneda tipoOtraMoneda;
    
    @Column(name="factor_conversion_otra_moneda", nullable=true)
    private Float factorConversionOtraMoneda;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dte")
    private List<Detalle> detalles;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dte")
    private List<SubtotalInformativo> subtotales;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dte")
    private List<DescuentoRecargoGlobal> descuentosRecargosGlobales;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dte")
    private List<Referencia> referencias;
    
}
```

The Detalle entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="detalle")
public class Detalle implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private DetallePK id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("dteId")
    private DocumentoTributarioElectronico dte;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<Subcantidad> subcantidades;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DetalleOtraMoneda> detalleOtraMoneda;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DistribucionDescuento> distribucionDescuento;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DistribucionRecargo> distribucionRecargo;
    
    @Column(name="agente_retenedor", columnDefinition="INT(11) DEFAULT 0")
    private Integer agenteRetenedor;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_faenamiento_carne", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseFaenamientoCarne;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_margen_comercializacion", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseMargenComercializacion;
    
    @Column(name="precio_unitario_neto_consumidor_final", nullable=true)
    private Long precioUnitarioNetoConsumidorFinal;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="rut_empresa", referencedColumnName="rut_empresa")
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_producto", referencedColumnName="codigo")
    private Producto producto;

    @Column(name="descripcion_adicional", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String descripcionAdicional;
    
    @Column(name="cantidad_referencia", nullable=true)
    private Float cantidadReferencia;
    
    @Column(name="cantidad", nullable=false)
    private Float cantidad;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_elaboracion", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaElaboracion;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_vencimiento", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaVencimiento;
    
    @Column(name="descuento_pct", nullable=true)
    private Float descuentoPct;
    
    @Column(name="descuento_monto", nullable=true)
    private Long descuentoMonto;
    
    @Column(name="recargo_pct", nullable=true)
    private Float recargoPct;
    
    @Column(name="recargo_monto", nullable=true)
    private Long recargoMonto;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_impuesto_retencion1", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    ImpuestoRetencion impuestoRetencion1;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_impuesto_retencion2", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    ImpuestoRetencion impuestoRetencion2;
    
    @Column(name="monto_item", nullable=false)
    private Long montoItem;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detallesPorSubtotal")
    private List<SubtotalInformativo> subtotales;
}
```

Now notice how are defined the Embeddable classes for each entity's id:

The DocumentoTributarioElectronicoPK class:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DocumentoTributarioElectronicoPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="rut_empresa", length=10, nullable=false)
    private String rutEmpresa;
    
    @Column(name="tipo_documento", nullable=false)
    private Integer tipoDocumento;
    
    @Column(name="numero", nullable=false)
    private Long numero;
}
```

The DetallePK class

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DetallePK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Embedded
    private DocumentoTributarioElectronicoPK dteId;
    
    @Column(name="numero_detalle", nullable=false)
    private Integer numeroDetalle;
}
```

When I run the application, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name tipo_documento in table detalle
```

But the column tipo_documento IS in detalle!

I'd wish to know what is wrong with both entities.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Please consider the fact that the DetallePK class is also embedded in other entities that are pointing to tables with a relationship many to one from each one of those tables to detalle.

**EDIT**: As requested, here is the current occurrences of referencedColumnName="tipo_documento". These are in another entity class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "detalles_subtotal", inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "rut_empresa", referencedColumnName = "rut_empresa"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_documento", referencedColumnName = "tipo_documento"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "numero", referencedColumnName = "numero"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "numero_detalle", referencedColumnName = "numero_detalle") }, joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "rut_empresa", referencedColumnName = "rut_empresa"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_documento", referencedColumnName = "tipo_documento"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "numero", referencedColumnName = "numero"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "numero_subtotal", referencedColumnName = "numero_subtotal") })
    private List<Detalle> detallesPorSubtotal;
```

**EDIT**: As per requested, I followed the accepted answer for the question in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31389777/1429387

This gives me another error:

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: cl.maraneda.neopos.entities.Detalle column: rut_empresa (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Obviously, map rut_empresa as non insertable is not an option

Comment: could you search your codebase for mentions of `referencedColumnName = "tipo_documento"`?

Comment: The mentions are in the definition of ```@JoinColumn``` in a ```@JoinTable``` in another Entity class.

As I said before, the column is in the table in the database

Comment: please post a part of this code with `@JoinColumn` and `@JoinTable`. I feel like there might be the root of your problem, after reading [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31389777/1429387).

Comment: Also, I followed the link you gave me and it gave me another error (see my third EDIT for details)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

After hitting my head against the wall over and over again, I came to a solution:

1. I had to rename the rut_empresa column in the table documento_tributario_electronico as rut_emisor, to avoid confusions.
2. It is correct to add the `@MapsId` annotation to specify the attribute in the embedded id class to be mapped for a `@OneToOne` or, in my case, a `@ManyToOne` relationship between the entities (in my case, from Detalle to DocumentoTributarioElectronico.
3. However, using `@MapsId` it is not enough if the embeddable class does not define directly some of the columns of the entity class that uses an instance of that embeddable class as the entity's id or if the application throws an exception complaining that there is a missing column that in fact exists in the database. In my case, neither the Detalle entity class nor the DetallePK embeddable class define directly the attributes pointing to the rut_emisor, tipo_documento and numero columns in the detalle table in the database using the `@Column` annotation, as they are defined in the DocumentoTributarioElectronicoPK object declared as an `@Embedded` attribute in the DetallePK class.
4. Also, you must be sure **there is no other `@Column` or `@JoinColumn` annotations pointing to the same columns among all other attributes in the entity class** or an exception will be thrown. To avoid this problem with `@JoinColumn`, you must follow these steps:

   - If there is only one conflicting column on a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` relationship from the conflicting entity to another entity, you only have to use the `@MapsId` annotation specifying the attribute in the another entity pointing to the column
   - If there is two or more conflicting columns on a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` relationship from the conflicting entity to another entity, and all of them are defined in a `@Embeddable` class whose instance is used as `@EmbeddedId` you have to use the `@MapsId` annotation with the value "<name_value_of_the_`@Entity`*annotation>.<name_of_the*`@EmbeddedId`_object}>. In my case, the Detalle entity has a `@OneToOne` relationship with this characteristics with another entity named Producto and the conflicting columns were defined in an embeddable class named ProductoPK whose instance is being used as embedded id attribute named id in Producto. As I didn't specified a name for the Producto entity, the value of `@MapsId` annotation in the conflicting attribute in Detalle is "producto.id".
   - If there is at least one conflicting column on a `@OneToMany` relationship from the conflicting entity to another entity, you must define a `@ManyToOne` attribute in the other entity with the specified `@JoinColumns` (use `@MapsId` if needed) and in the conflicting attribute of the conflicting entity, add the mappedBy parameter to the `@OneToMany` annotation.

The resulting Detalle class with all the corrections is as follows:

```
package cl.maraneda.neopos.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import cl.maraneda.neopos.entities.pk.DetallePK;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="detalle")
public class Detalle implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private DetallePK id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("dteId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_documento", referencedColumnName = "tipo_documento")
    @JoinColumn(name = "numero", referencedColumnName = "numero")
    @JoinColumn(name = "rut_empresa", referencedColumnName = "rut_emisor")
    private DocumentoTributarioElectronico dte;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<Subcantidad> subcantidades;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DetalleOtraMoneda> detalleOtraMoneda;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DistribucionDescuento> distribucionDescuento;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detalle")
    private List<DistribucionRecargo> distribucionRecargo;
    
    @Column(name="agente_retenedor", columnDefinition="INT(11) DEFAULT 0")
    private Integer agenteRetenedor;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_faenamiento_carne", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseFaenamientoCarne;
    
    @Column(name="monto_base_margen_comercializacion", nullable=true)
    private Long montoBaseMargenComercializacion;
    
    @Column(name="precio_unitario_neto_consumidor_final", nullable=true)
    private Long precioUnitarioNetoConsumidorFinal;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("producto.id")
    private Producto producto;

    @Column(name="descripcion_adicional", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String descripcionAdicional;
    
    @Column(name="cantidad_referencia", nullable=true)
    private Float cantidadReferencia;
    
    @Column(name="cantidad", nullable=false)
    private Float cantidad;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_elaboracion", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaElaboracion;
    
    @Column(name="fecha_vencimiento", nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaVencimiento;
    
    @Column(name="descuento_pct", nullable=true)
    private Float descuentoPct;
    
    @Column(name="descuento_monto", nullable=true)
    private Long descuentoMonto;
    
    @Column(name="recargo_pct", nullable=true)
    private Float recargoPct;
    
    @Column(name="recargo_monto", nullable=true)
    private Long recargoMonto;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_impuesto_retencion1", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    ImpuestoRetencion impuestoRetencion1;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_impuesto_retencion2", referencedColumnName="codigo", nullable=true)
    ImpuestoRetencion impuestoRetencion2;
    
    @Column(name="monto_item", nullable=false)
    private Long montoItem;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="detallesPorSubtotal")
    private List<SubtotalInformativo> subtotales;   
}
```

Many thanks to all who replied to my problem and tried to help me.