# Update field on daily basis with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which I have record of patients, for example `id`, `name`, `time`, `date`, `regularity`, etc. Now I want to add a new field `medical-record-number`, I mean another integer field and auto-increment it on daily basis. I use MySQL and PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use `id` as `medical-record-number`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table#answer-217952

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $sql = "ALTER TABLE `patient` ADD `medical-record-number` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT";
    mysqli_query($sql);
```