# Same primary key in a table

Tags: sql, database, primary-key

I just started learning SQL in a book, and I'm stack at understanding the concept of the primary key.

Here I have to explain little about these tables in this db.

**The Order table** stores customer orders but not order details. Each order is uniquely numbered.

**The orderItems table** stores the actual items in each order, one row per item per order.

I thought primary key could be used for the identical column in a table, and same values couldn't be inserted. 
But I found couple of the same values are inserted in the primary key(order_num, order_items) in orderItems

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the concept of a "composite key".

Comment: It's called a composite primary key, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table