# Modifying second column for primary key

Tags: mysql

Hello i have table which has a primary key now on the basis of my need i have to create another primary key means the second primary key but its showing this error message

```
"ALTER TABLE `abc` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`zzz`)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1068 - Multiple primary key define"
```

Here is the command:

```
ALTER TABLE `ABC` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`ZZZ`)
```

Comment: One table can have only 1 primary key at a time. You can make it unique key rahter. So your approach is wrong.

Comment: whatever your need is,but you can't have two primary keys in a table,rather you can have composite primary key,check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to have more than 1 primary key on single table. You can have composite primary key on combination of two columns.

Comment: Its possible i have created in past but i dont remember the commands

Comment: No its not possible. Which database you used?

Comment: @user3475078 i meant in which database you created 2 primary keys on single table?

Comment: ya in single table i had two primary keys

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one primary key. Change the first one or add a unique constraint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table