# Android App crashes at the beginning: Database Sqlite

Tags: android

I'm developping an android application, and while I was programming, there was no problem or error, and when I did run it on device, the logcat:

```
    11-16 09:27:29.930 4261-4261/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-16 09:27:29.956 4261-4261/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-16 09:27:30.188 4261-4261/com.example.root.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-16 09:27:30.616 4261-4261/com.example.root.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "KEYMatriculeINTEGER": syntax error
11-16 09:27:30.617 4261-4261/com.example.root.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-16 09:27:30.619 4261-4261/com.example.root.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.root.myapplication, PID: 4261
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.myapplication/com.example.root.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "KEYMatriculeINTEGER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEYMatriculeINTEGER PRIMARY KEYNomTEXTPrenomTEXTTypeTEXT)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "KEYMatriculeINTEGER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEYMatriculeINTEGER PRIMARY KEYNomTEXTPrenomTEXTTypeTEXT)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1752)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1682)
                                                                                  at model.sqlite.data.ModelHelper.onCreate(ModelHelper.java:101)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:333)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
                                                                                  at com.example.root.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

the mainactivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialisation des références
    final EditText txtTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtTO);
    Button btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnx);
    TextView btnreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

    //Ouverture de la BD
    dbhelper = new ModelHelper(this);
    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String TO = txtTo.getText().toString();


            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ModelHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + ModelHelper.KEY_MATRICULE + " ='?'  ", new String[]{"TO"});
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    //Retrouver le TO dans la base de données USER
                    String nom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_NOM));
                    String prenom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PRENOM));
                    //message pour affichage du msg de réussite de cnx
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Passer à la page suivante
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kamiActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nom", nom);
                    intent.putExtra("prenom", prenom);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    //Removing MainActivity[Login Screen] from the stack for preventing back button press.
                    finish();
                } else {

                    //I am showing Alert Dialog Box here for alerting user about wrong credentials
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Alert");
                    builder.setMessage("Votre TO n'existe pas, veuillez vous inscrire avant s'il vous plait.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                    //-------Alert Dialog Code Snippet End Here
                }
            }




        }

        });
}

public void Reg(View view) {
    Intent myint = new Intent(this,signup.class);
}
```

}

and then the Modelhelper:

```
    package model.sqlite.data;

import android.util.Log;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.sqlite.data.user;
import model.sqlite.data.question;
import model.sqlite.data.theme;
import model.sqlite.data.answer;

public class ModelHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOG = "ModelHelper";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "model";

    // Table names
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "User";
    private static final String TABLE_QUESTION = "Question";
    private static final String TABLE_THEME = "Theme";
    private static final String TABLE_ANSWER = "Answer";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ID_QUESTION = "ID_question";
    public static final String KEY_MATRICULE = "Matricule";
    private static final String KEY_ID_THEME = "ID_Theme";

    // Table User columns
    public static final String KEY_NOM = "Nom";
    public static final String KEY_PRENOM = "Prenom";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "Type";
    // Table Question columns
    private static final String KEY_QUESTION = "Question";
    private static final String KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE = "Profil cible";
    private static final String KEY_REGLE = "Regle";
    private static final String KEY_PLANACT = "PlanAct";
    // Table Theme columns
    private static final String KEY_THEME = "Theme";
    // Table Answer columns
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "Date";
    private static final String KEY_REPONSE = "Reponse";
    private static final String KEY_COMMENTAIRE = "Commentaire";
    // User table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
    +    KEY_MATRICULE + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_NOM + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_PRENOM + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_TYPE + "TEXT"
    +    ")";

    // Question table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_QUESTION + "("
    +    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_ID_QUESTION + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_QUESTION + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_REGLE + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_PLANACT + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_ID_THEME + "INTEGER"
    +    ")";

    // Theme table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_THEME = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_THEME + "("
    +    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_ID_THEME + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_THEME + "TEXT"
    +    ")";

    // Answer table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ANSWER = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ANSWER + "("
    +    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_MATRICULE + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_ID_QUESTION + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_DATE + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY"
    +    KEY_REPONSE + "TEXT"
    +    KEY_COMMENTAIRE + "TEXT"
    +    ")";


    public ModelHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_THEME);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ANSWER);
    }

     @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_THEME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ANSWER);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // closing database
    public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }


    // CRUD operations for User

    public long createuser(user arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MATRICULE, arg.getmatricule());
        values.put(KEY_NOM, arg.getnom());
        values.put(KEY_PRENOM, arg.getprenom());
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, arg.gettype());

        return db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    }

    public user getuser(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }

        user entry = new user();
        entry.setmatricule(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MATRICULE)));
        entry.setnom(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOM)));
        entry.setprenom(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRENOM)));
        entry.settype(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE)));

        return entry;
    }

    public List<user> getAlluser() {
        List<user> list = new ArrayList<user>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                user entry = new user();
                entry.setmatricule(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MATRICULE)));
                entry.setnom(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOM)));
                entry.setprenom(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRENOM)));
                entry.settype(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE)));

                // adding to todo list
                list.add(entry);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }

    public long updateuser(user arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_MATRICULE, arg.getmatricule());
        values.put(KEY_NOM, arg.getnom());
        values.put(KEY_PRENOM, arg.getprenom());
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, arg.gettype());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_USER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(arg.getId()) });
    }

    public void deleteuser(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }


    // CRUD operations for Question

    public long createquestion(question arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID_QUESTION, arg.getiDQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, arg.getquestion());
        values.put(KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE, arg.getprofilCible());
        values.put(KEY_REGLE, arg.getregle());
        values.put(KEY_PLANACT, arg.getplanAct());
        values.put(KEY_ID_THEME, arg.getiDTheme());

        return db.insert(TABLE_QUESTION, null, values);
    }

    public question getquestion(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTION + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }

        question entry = new question();
        entry.setiDQuestion(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_QUESTION)));
        entry.setquestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION)));
        entry.setprofilCible(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE)));
        entry.setregle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REGLE)));
        entry.setplanAct(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PLANACT)));
        entry.setiDTheme(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_THEME)));

        return entry;
    }

    public List<question> getAllquestion() {
        List<question> list = new ArrayList<question>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTION;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                question entry = new question();
                entry.setiDQuestion(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_QUESTION)));
                entry.setquestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION)));
                entry.setprofilCible(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE)));
                entry.setregle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REGLE)));
                entry.setplanAct(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PLANACT)));
                entry.setiDTheme(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_THEME)));

                // adding to todo list
                list.add(entry);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }

    public long updatequestion(question arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ID_QUESTION, arg.getiDQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, arg.getquestion());
        values.put(KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE, arg.getprofilCible());
        values.put(KEY_REGLE, arg.getregle());
        values.put(KEY_PLANACT, arg.getplanAct());
        values.put(KEY_ID_THEME, arg.getiDTheme());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_QUESTION, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(arg.getId()) });
    }

    public void deletequestion(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_QUESTION, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }


    // CRUD operations for Theme

    public long createtheme(theme arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID_THEME, arg.getiDTheme());
        values.put(KEY_THEME, arg.gettheme());

        return db.insert(TABLE_THEME, null, values);
    }

    public theme gettheme(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_THEME + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }

        theme entry = new theme();
        entry.setiDTheme(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_THEME)));
        entry.settheme(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_THEME)));

        return entry;
    }

    public List<theme> getAlltheme() {
        List<theme> list = new ArrayList<theme>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_THEME;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                theme entry = new theme();
                entry.setiDTheme(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_THEME)));
                entry.settheme(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_THEME)));

                // adding to todo list
                list.add(entry);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }

    public long updatetheme(theme arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ID_THEME, arg.getiDTheme());
        values.put(KEY_THEME, arg.gettheme());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_THEME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(arg.getId()) });
    }

    public void deletetheme(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_THEME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }


    // CRUD operations for Answer

    public long createanswer(answer arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MATRICULE, arg.getmatricule());
        values.put(KEY_ID_QUESTION, arg.getiDQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, arg.getdate());
        values.put(KEY_REPONSE, arg.getreponse());
        values.put(KEY_COMMENTAIRE, arg.getcommentaire());

        return db.insert(TABLE_ANSWER, null, values);
    }

    public answer getanswer(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWER + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }

        answer entry = new answer();
        entry.setmatricule(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MATRICULE)));
        entry.setiDQuestion(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_QUESTION)));
        entry.setdate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
        entry.setreponse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPONSE)));
        entry.setcommentaire(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMMENTAIRE)));

        return entry;
    }

    public List<answer> getAllanswer() {
        List<answer> list = new ArrayList<answer>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWER;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                answer entry = new answer();
                entry.setmatricule(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MATRICULE)));
                entry.setiDQuestion(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_QUESTION)));
                entry.setdate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
                entry.setreponse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPONSE)));
                entry.setcommentaire(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMMENTAIRE)));

                // adding to todo list
                list.add(entry);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }

    public long updateanswer(answer arg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_MATRICULE, arg.getmatricule());
        values.put(KEY_ID_QUESTION, arg.getiDQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, arg.getdate().toString());
        values.put(KEY_REPONSE, arg.getreponse());
        values.put(KEY_COMMENTAIRE, arg.getcommentaire());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_ANSWER, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(arg.getId()) });
    }

    public void deleteanswer(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_ANSWER, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }


}
```

I saw that the problem is using the int: matricule but I checked everywhere I didn't found an error or a problem in the code.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553760/android-sqlite-syntax-error-code-1-while-compiling-create-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.root.myapplication/com.example.root.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "KEYMatriculeINTEGER":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE User(id INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEYMatriculeINTEGER PRIMARY KEYNomTEXTPrenomTEXTTypeTEXT)

You are missing some commas:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
+    KEY_MATRICULE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
+    KEY_NOM + " TEXT, "
+    KEY_PRENOM + " TEXT, "
+    KEY_TYPE + " TEXT"
+    ")";
```

Comment: I tried spaces but didn't work. still having the same error

Comment: the same one? Are you sure? It's maybe in another SQL statement. The first error is very clear..."CREATE TABLE User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEYMatriculeINTEGER PRIMARY KEYNomTEXTPrenomTEXTTypeTEXT)"

Comment: It's too long I can't copy it here

Comment: He needs commas ',' not spaces

Comment: yes, I will try to redo the Data part manually, it was generated so the code wasn't that good I think.