# How to define composite primary key in SilverStripe ORM/Dataobject

Tags: php, silverstripe

SilverStripe's DataObject gives us the following to start with:

ID - primary key

But how do you define a composite key (primary key composed of 2 or more columns)?  I've searched the documentation and can not find this information anywhere.

Comment: Silverstripe experts please shed light on how  composite primary keys is handle in this framework.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the primary key, but you can set a unique index instead. It should give you a sort-a-like result as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217948/6251886).

```
class YourDataObject extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'MyField' => 'Varchar',
        'MyOtherField' => 'Varchar'
    ];

    private static $indexes = array(
        'MyIndexName' => array(
            'type' => 'unique', // changed this to unique
            'value' => '"MyField","MyOtherField"'
        )
    );
}
```

With this code, it is not possible to create a `YourDataObject` with `MyField = 'test'` and `MyOtherField = 'othertest'` if a there already is a record with BOTH those values in the database. It is possible to create a `YourDataObject` with only the `MyField` as test and `MyOtherField` as something else.

However, it is recommended to check on this before you write it to your database, as you would get a user-unfriedly error in your ModelAdmin.

Code copied from the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/indexes/)

Comment: Don't put your code in the ModelAdmin, but in your DataObject.