# Foreign key reference aspnet_Membership(UserId)

Tags: mysql

I have created this table:

```sql
create table UserQuestion
(QuestiuonID int identity,
UserID uniqueIdentifier primary key foreign key references aspnet_Users(UserId),
QuestionTitle Nvarchar(max),
QuestionContext nvarchar(max),
)
```

I have a problem with it. It looks like I cannot have two fields, where field no. 1 is set as Identity and another one set as Primary.

Is there any way that I can make a table like this that works?

My second question is: what is the benefit of using a foreign key when it's not fetching the data from other table, and I have to give the value to this field manually in my program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple primary keys in a single table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table)

Comment: Improved code formatting, and tightened up the prose (spelling, grammar, etc)