# Auto increment with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, key, primary-key, auto-increment

I am not entirely sure what to search so I apologize if this is in fact a duplicate.

I have a table (or at least would like to) as follows:

- ID
- Company Name
- SomeOtherInfo

The primary key would be `ID` and `Company name` (composite primary key). What I would like is so that the ID auto increments on each company.

Ex:

```
1-google
2-google
3-google
1-yahoo
4-google
2-yahoo
```

This way they are always unique, but each one increments for each company individually.

Is this possible from simple SQL create commands, would rather not have 2 tables and join them using a secondary ID.

Let me know, thanks.

Comment: That'll **strongly depend** on which **concrete** database system you're using. **SQL** as the query language doesn't have any such feature - but maybe some vendor-specific extensions would offer something like this. Please add a relevant tag like `oracle`, `postgresql`, `mysql`, `sql-server`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using to your post!

Comment: Standard SQL has IDENTITY and SEQUENCE both of which are auto sequence generator features. The standard IDENTITY and SEQUENCE keywords are supported by most DBMSs but MySQL uses the AUTO_INCREMENT instead of IDENTITY and has no equivalent of SEQUENCE.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow the question.  Create a single table with an identity on the ID column.  Then create a unique index on the Company Name.

MySql Version

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    CompanyID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CompanyName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    OtherData  varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID)
); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CompanyUniqueComposite
ON Company (CompanyID , CompanyName );
```

Comment: CompanyID is a way of referencing the record.  A combination of CompanyName and SomeOtherInfo must be unique to prevent creating duplicate records.  This assumes I understand what the OP is asking.....

Comment: I was looking for an example to see if it was possible to do this sort of thing in mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6383117/3339122 where I just insets the company name, and otherinfo and the ID increments up by one, for each company (as seen in the example he gave)