# primary keys in a Junction Table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can you make two keys in a junction table as primary keys.

I'm trying to create two primary keys in a junction table.

One will be a primary and the other will be a foreign key but also a primary key as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple primary keys in a single table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table)

Comment: but the primary keys must also act as a foreign key as well

Comment: All the things you note are more or less possible (technically you can only have 1 primary key in a table but many unique indices). Sometimes it's just easier to try the thing.

Comment: You can only have one Primary Key, but you can have as many foreign keys as you need. In a Key that it´s not primary, you can also set that it´s unique, not null, so you don´t need two primary keys.

Comment: Thanks all for the help.