# What wrong with my code because there is no error but I cant run it?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Grade (
StudentNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ClassNumber INT(10) NOT NULL,
Grade DOUBLE(3),
PRIMARY KEY(StudentNumber, ClassNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(StudentNumber)REFERENCES student(StudentNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(ClassNumber)REFERENCES class(ClassNumber)
)
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '), PRIMARY KEY(StudentNumber, ClassNumber), FOREIGN
>   KEY(StudentNumber)REFERENC' at line 4

Comment: PRIMARY KEY(StudentNumber, ClassNumber) ??? As per documentation, you must use only one primary key per table.

Comment: firstly, thank you sir but isnt there a composite primary key where I'm combining two data from existed tables into a new table?

Comment: @SanthoshArun it is true. Visit here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table

Comment: @Santhiosh Arun -where it is written. we can declare composite key also

Comment: @AnWan have you created your student and class tabel before running above script.

Comment: @Kandy yes, I have done both tables already

Comment: Thank you everyone, I really appreciate it and I have found the soloution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use double you have to add how many digits it should have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Grade (

StudentNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

ClassNumber INT(10) NOT NULL,

Grade DOUBLE(3, 2),

PRIMARY KEY(StudentNumber, ClassNumber),

FOREIGN KEY(StudentNumber)REFERENCES student(StudentNumber),

FOREIGN KEY(ClassNumber)REFERENCES class(ClassNumber) )
```