# Laravel foreign_key Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrderProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('order_id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
            $table->bigIncrements('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('order_product');
    }
}


I expected to create a pivot table, but when I run the "php artisan migrate" it give me this: 

    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

(SQL: create table `order_product` (`order_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `product_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key) default character set utf8mb4 collate
'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

```
What is wrong with my code? :(
```

Comment: I think `bigIncrements()` will also make the key primary and you can't have multiple primary keys in the same table. Although the error seems to be foreign key related, so I'm not a 100% sure.

Comment: `bigIncrements()` makes Auto-incrementing `UNSIGNED BIGINT` (primary key) equivalent column.  MySQL does not allow two primary keys to exists in one table.. I assume you need to use `$table->bigInteger('product_id');` which should make a `BIGINT` datatype.

Comment: Change the two `bigIncrements` to `unsignedBigInteger`. You are trying to create two auto increment column in a pivot.

Comment: I change bigIncrements to unsignedBigInteger and it works. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the first line as `$table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();`  The remaining lines with `bigIncrements` change to `bigInteger()` instead.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}
```

Even better, you can use [Eloquent's built in relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) instead of manhandling the intermediate pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

With your migration you're trying to create **two** *primary keys* in the same table, this is the error you get.

When you declare a field as `bigIncrements` you're asking laravel to create a `auto incrementing primary key`; you have two of this declaration in the same table and this is not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217945/can-i-have-multiple-primary-keys-in-a-single-table).

Seen that you want to create a `pivot` table you don't really need a *primary key* if you don't want to have a `Model` representing the intermediate table `order_product`.

To remove the error you have to use `unsignedBigInteger` for the two foreing keys, because the fields they are referring (the `id` columns of `orders` and `products` tables) are `unsigned bigintegers` i.e.:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}
```

In case you want to have a `composite primary key` on the two foreing keys you can write this inside your migration:

```php
$table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id']);
```

This line ensure also that you don't get duplicate lines (`order_id`, `product_id`) in your table. You can have the same effect declaring a `composite unique index`:

```php
$table->unique(['order_id', 'product_id']);
```

If you wants instead *one* `primary key` you can add a `id` column just writing this line to the migration above:

```php
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

But this is really useful only if you want a [intermediate table Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

BTW apart for the error with the `bigIncrements` the naming conventions used for the pivot table and the fields are already perfect.

Comment: @serg11u Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it solved your problem.